# Disposing user control from same usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have wpf application having  Mainform,I am adding a custom usercontrol dynamically;Custom user control hase close button which should dispose the usercontrol.I am not able to dispose the same usercontrol from itself( how ever I can do this in winform application). Right now I am using custom event delegate to achieve this functionality( from mainwindow ,by remoing control from grid).

Can any one suggest better approach?

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ChildControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ChildControl : UserControl
{
    public delegate void onCloseOfControl();
    public event onCloseOfControl CloseBtnEvent;

    //This control will be added into
    // grid of Mainwindow.
    public ChildControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //I want to remove this whole control
    private void btnCloseOnChild_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Dispose();
        //Not Possible In wpf,I could do this in Winforms.

        //Now I am wrting this logic

        if (CloseBtnEvent != null)
            CloseBtnEvent();
        //Now main window will get this event,and I will
        //remove this control from grid.
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: "I am not able to dispose the same usercontrol from itself", what do you mean by this? What did you do? What happened?

Comment: I have not implemented IDisposable interfeace,in winform application I was getting this.Dispose() method,here in wpf I am not getting it.

Comment: So you're saying that you want to dispose a control that does not implement `IDisposable`? If it does not implement that interface then you can't/shouldn't dispose of it. What exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I am just comparing my previous winform app with current wpf app, and finding better solution to close usercontrol from within itself.(If possible).

Comment: Firstly you wrote something about disposing, then something about removing a control from a grid. It is not clear for me. Can you share some code with us showing what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general in WPF, `UserControl`s do *not* need to be 'disposed'... they do *not* implement the [`IDisposable` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). They do  *not* contain any services or other members that require disposing. A WPF `UserControl` bears very little resemblance to a WinForms `UserControl` and the sooner that you stop comparing WPF to WinForms, the better you will learn WPF.

The simple act of removing or replacing a `UserControl` is enough to release whatever resources it may have taken up. We often to use `DataTemplate`s in WPF to get the Framework to display a `UserControl` for us:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UsersViewModel}">
    <Views:UsersView />
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

When doing this, all you need to do to replace a `UserControl` is this:

```
ViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UserControl should implement an event taht is triggered when you hit the close button. Your Form should then react on this event by disposing the control. You can't dispose the control from within itself.

Comment: "Your Form should then react on this event by disposing the control."
For this I am removing the usercontrol from Mainwindow on close button event.